# Conditional VLOOKUP with unique match by column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I want to do the following:
[image]

The BUY and SELL area is done and ordered by date descending, but I need help to calculate the profit of each article.

What I need is to have the PROFIT Area filled like in the example.

My idea is doing it with a VLOOKUP, but I need it to use only one Transaction ID each time (one for BUY, other from SELL).

EDIT:
I want all the BUY Transaction ID on "Column I" and the nearest SELL Transaction ID on his side on "Column J".
If there's isn't a SELL Transaction, put only the BUY Transaction ID and leave the SELL Transaction ID in BLANK.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(J3,$E$3:$G$8,3,0)-VLOOKUP(I3,$A$3:$C$9,3,0)` should do the trick for you if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Hi @ian0411 , no... I don't explain good I think. What I want is to get all the BUY Transaction ID on the "I Column" and the first SELL Transaction ID on the "J Column" without repeating any of the SELL or BUY Transaction ID.

Comment: Removed the [tag:excel-formula] as the screenshot shows a Google Sheets spreadsheet and because [tag:gs-vlookup] is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profit is calculated only when you sell smth, so I suggest to continue the second table SELL:

[image]

If we use FIFO: first in → first out, then we want to get first apple from BUY table. To get this use `index`:

`=INDEX(FILTER({$A$3:$A,$C$3:$C},$B$3:$B=F3),COUNTIF(F$2:F3,F3))`

Drag this formula down. Then use `=G3-I3` for profit.

---

For your regional settings please try:

`=INDEX(FILTER({$A$3:$A\$C$3:$C};$B$3:$B=F3);COUNTIF(F$2:F3;F‌​3))`

**Edit**

As @anonymous  mentioned, if you need first last value (earliest), the formula is to be sorted by row number since you have no dates:

`=INDEX(QUERY(FILTER({row($A$3:$A)\$A$3:$A\$C$3:$C};$B$3:$B=F3);"select Col2, Col3 order by Col1 desc");COUNTIF(F$2:F3,F3))`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I think that your solution is great, but I can't do it work. It says: **Error
FILTER has gap sizes that do not match. Expected number of rows: 1998. Number of columns: 1. Actual number of rows: 999. Number of columns: 1.**. And also, I don't know why, but I have to change your commas to semicolon, like this: **=INDEX(FILTER({$A$3:$A;$C$3:$C};$B$3:$B=F3);COUNTIF(F$2:F3;F3))**

Comment: I've added sample formula for you. Also try go to File → Spreadsheet Settings → Locale. Change to US.

Comment: OP's data is sorted in  descending order(Which means 
Last row will be first as per FIFO)

Comment: @anonymous, you are right and it makes formula more complicated.

Comment: It works well, buy I don't know why some rows are failing. can you check my example? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16_FM3rQbbGODwKSE_8-8akGA-H-iMbwW9Gh7YopYUVQ/edit?usp=sharing it seems that the error is only when there's only one item type